# Чтение Java DataOutputStream в C++

Tags: java, c++, сокет, tcp

Всех приветствую.

Все еще пытаюсь создать приложение video straming'a (client-server-client).

Суть:

Есть 2 клиента. 1 - отправитель, 2 - получатель.

1 шлет размер картинки, саму картинку. Сервер её получает и отправляет сначала размер картинки, а потом и саму картинку, другому клиенту.

Для C++ сокета я использую BOOST::Asio.

Появилась такая проблема:

Мне нужно на C++ сначала получить размер изображения, который отсылает Java, а затем и само изображение записать в массов байтов.

При чтении изображение Java'вским DataInputStream (на стороне сервера) - проблем никаких не возникает.

Но если я попытаюсь получать изображения Java сервера на C++ - появляется огромная проблема, в виде того, что я даже не знаю, что шлет сервер.

Что он шлет конкретно:

[image: FullData]

Как я тут заметил, C++ все же выдает символ начала чтения размера изображения и символ конца размера изображения:

[image: Exactly]

Вот тут Java их отсылает:

[image: Java code]

Как мне можно получить размер получаемого изображения, а далее записать все изображение, к примеру, в byte[IMG_SIZE]?

Что-то типа такого:

```
int IMAGE_SIZE = SOCKET.READ_SOMETHING...

byte[IMAGE_SIZE] img = ??....
```

Java code:

```
private void ReadImage(){

        while (true) {
            try {
                int token = is.readInt();
                if (token == 4) {
                    dos.writeInt(4);
                    if (is.readUTF().equals("#@@#")) {

                        dos.writeUTF("#@@#");

                        int imgLength = is.readInt();

                        is.readUTF();

                        listener.onDataReceived(imgLength);

                        dos.writeInt(imgLength);
                        dos.writeUTF("-@@-");
                        dos.flush();

                        byte[] buffer = new byte[imgLength];
                        int len = 0;
                        while (len < imgLength) {
                            len += is.read(buffer, len, imgLength - len);
                        }
                        dos.write(buffer);
                        dos.flush();

                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                try {
                    ReconnectSockets();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

C++ Code:

```
void DataManager::ReadData()
{
    boost::array<char, 40000> buf;
    boost::system::error_code error;
    size_t len = socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf), error);

    string data(buf.begin(), buf.end());

    cout << data << endl;
}
```

Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Comment: `string data(buf.begin(), buf.begin() + len);`

Comment: @VTT, а что мне это даст? Мне нужно сначала вообще знать, какой размер данных получать. Размер данных присылается примерно так: ##@@## 34333 --@@--, а далее идет само изображение

Comment: вы сами написали, что проблема в том, что не знаете, что шлет сервер. Это получается из-за того, что вы бухаете в вывод весь мусор из буфера. Изображение у вас не отсылается, так как вызывается onDataReceived.  замените картинки с текстом на текст

Comment: @VTT, обновил вопрос. Насчет onDataReceived - изображение прекрасно отсылается, проверено.

Comment: [`writeUtf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/DataOutput.html#writeUTF(java.lang.String)) пишет строку в своем формате (два байта с длиной строки и символы строки в modified utf). Вообще я бы отказался от строковых маркеров начала и конца изображения, т.к. у вас tcp, байты читаются в том порядке, в котором пишутся и никуда ваша картинка не денется